# How to add a numeric filter on kibana dashboard?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I have a field that contains numbers. I want a filter that shows all logs that are less than a constant value. 
When I try to add a new query filter, all I can see is a query string option.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

If you are talking about the query field a syntax like this works:

```
field:<10
```

Will find just records with a `field` value less than 10.  Found this by experimentation one day -- don't know if it's documented anywhere.

Comment: There is a link to the appropriate documentation inside Kibana itself, when you click on a query's coloured dot (which allows you to change the colour as well the query type). A real-world example: assume you log the number of microseconds Apache took to service a response, and you ship this out as a JSON integer. I create a few queries that selects events with durations in different ranges. Each query looks a bit like  duration_micros:(>=10000 AND <500000)   For some queries, I make them a topN query to break down on content-type, which I also log.

Comment: It's strange that it's important to not have a [space] between the operator and the number. I mean this not works: field:< 10 (but this: field: <10 and this field:<10)

Comment: The syntax is documented in the "[Query String Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_ranges_2)" topic of the Elasticsearch Reference.

Comment: Note, doesn't appear that this works for post query values. For example, you cant do `Count:>100`